# Remove element from List within foreach

Tags: c#, xna

I have a `List<Buoy>` and I want to remove the `Buoy` that is hit by my `Ship`.

```
foreach (var Chest in Chests) {
    if (Chest.Bounds.Intersects (Ship.Bounds)) {
        Player.Score += 1;
    }
}
```

I have written the `Dispose()`-method and I want to set the specific `Chest` to `null`. How can I do this, without getting the error I am assigning something to `Chest` because it is a foreach iteration variable.

Comment: CodeCaster: I have written this question, because I didn't understand the above question, as it is much more extensive as the work I am doing.

Comment: What part don't you understand? `for (int i = Chests.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)` will work.

Comment: CodeCaster: I don't understand it, because if I have three `Ship`s on my screen and I hit the second in the list, how can I remove it based on which one I hit?

Comment: Nevermind, I misread (not in the least because your title (remove) doesn't match your question (set null)). There most definitely is another duplicate somewhere. Are you sure you want to set `Chest` to `null` though?

Comment: @LVBen: I thought my question to be clear, I will edit.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Think of it as picking up a PowerUp. You hit it with the Ship and it disappears, thus being removed from memory.

I thought the way to go was using null?

Comment: And then in the next iteration of `foreach (var Chest in Chests)` you check each `Chest` for `null`, right? Otherwise `Chest.Bounds` will throw a NullReferenceException. Easier to remove them from the list if you won't need them again...

Comment: No, I'm checking whether any of the Chests is in collision with Ship in the `foreach`, and if there is Collision, I want to remove the Chest that is being hit.

Answer (score 4):

`foreach` is great, but it does have an unfortunate side effect of making the iterator immutable.  One workaround would be to use another list to keep track of which `Buoy`s to remove.

```
     List<Buoy> ChestsToRemove = new List<Buoy>();
     foreach (Buoy chest in Chests)
     {
        if (Buoy.Bounds.Intersects(Ship.Bounds))
        {
           Player.Score += 1;
           ChestsToRemove.Add(chest);
        }
     }
     foreach (Buoy chestToRemove in ChestsToRemove)
     {
        Chests.Remove(chestToRemove);
     }
```

Comment: The "Kill list" approach is also a very common way of solving this problem. +1

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a real need to couple the discovery of which things you're intersecting with removal from the list of all things.

```
var collisions = Chests.Where(c => c.Bounds.Intersects(Ship.Bounds)).ToList();
Player.Score += collisions.Count();
Chests = Chests.Except(collisions);
```

Comment: If `Chests` is a `List<Chest>` and not an `IEnumerable<Chest>` you'll need to call `ToList()` on the last line as well.

Answer (score 1):

you can also remove like on example below

```
foreach (var Chest in Chests) {
    if (Chest.Bounds.Intersects (Ship.Bounds)) {
        Player.Score += 1;
        Chest.IsActive = false;
    }
}

Chests.RemoveAll(c => !c.IsActive)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem when you want to remove items from a list you're iterating over is that the enumerator loses track of where you are in the list.

It's a bit like sawing a branch on which you are sitting. You shoudn't do it because it will have unecptected behaviour.

Now, how can this be solved?

Quite easily, you need make a copy of your list, iterate over your copy, and remove the items from your original list.

Sounds like a lot of code, but the only thing that you need to do is add `ToList()` in your foreach statement.

Like so:

```
foreach (var Chest in Chests.ToList()) {
    if (Chest.Bounds.Intersects (Ship.Bounds)) {
        Player.Score += 1;
    }
}
```

Now, why does this work?

It's because `ToList()` creates a copy of your list in memory. So basiclly, your iterating over a copy of the collection right now.

So this apporach should work.

Comment: Chests doesn't have the method `ToList()`, as it already is a List. ;)

Comment: But it doesn't answer the question besides adding the needed "ToList()" with no explanation as to *why* that is important. Its also a very poor common answer. The OP's comment to that effect makes it painfully clear that the why is important, and missing.

Comment: I'm editing my answer, I just was in a hurry. I'm sorry, I just wanted to help the person :-)

Comment: Much, much better now. Thank you for the edit! You could add the remove code as well, since setting to null is not generally the right approach.

Comment: You're welcome. As as I told, I'm sorry for the poor answer :-)

Comment: Chests should be an IList<T> normally instead of a List. Is there a possibility for you to change?

Comment: I can change that to an IList<T>, I suppose. ;)

Comment: Than it's a good idea to do so, since an IList<T> is an interface, so your list can be easily swapped with some other custom implementation of IList